# Why are this two definition of smooth manifold equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I would like to prove that $\Sigma$ is a $k$-smooth manifold if and only if it is locally a graph of an opportune function.

I mean that for every $x \in \Sigma$ there exists an open set $U$ and a function $h : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{d-k}$ such that $\Sigma \cap U=graph(h)\cap U$

I tried using a regular parametrization $\varphi$ and using the fact that the rank of $d \varphi$ is $k$ but I do not know where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by an opportune function?

Comment: Fix a point $p=\phi(0)\in\Sigma$. The rank of $d\phi(0)$ is $k$. Show that $T_p\Sigma = \text{im}(d\phi(0))$ projects isomorphically onto some coordinate $k$-plane in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Hint (in case you started with the definition of a submanifold as a level set): Implicit function theorem (or Dini’s theorem, as you call it in Pisa :) ) 

Comment: When you see “locally as a graph of a function”, 95% of the times Ulisse Dini is hiding behind the door.

Comment: To add to Ted's hint, to show that $T_p \Sigma$ projects isomorphically onto some coordinate $k$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism (this may not be necessary perhaps...)